# Spring Data-Rest + Spring MVC

Tags: spring, rest

I am mixing Spring MVC with Spring Data-Rest and my User repository is of this form:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "users", path = "users")
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

My servletContext.xml has the following properties:

```
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration">   </bean>


    <bean id="viewResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

Right now my paths are of the form `/myapp/users`. How can I change it to be `/myapp/rest/users`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding configuration hook to your `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` bean:

```java
@Configuration
@Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)
public class CustomConfigWithBasePath  extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration 
{
  @Override
  protected void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) 
  {
    super.configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(config);
    try 
    {
      config.setBaseUri(new URI("/rest"));
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) 
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Otherwise, you can configure the `BaseURI` bean with a custom base uri as follows:

```xml
<bean id="baseUri" class="org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.BaseUri">
  <constructor-arg value="/rest"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration"
  p:baseUri-ref="baseUri">
</bean>
```

Comment: Would that be possible in xml configuration?

Comment: I was just adding an alternative version :)

Comment: how to change the url of the spring data rest browser?